# riak-shell giving error as Not connected to riak

Tags: riak-ts

my riak-shell was running when my riak.conf containing as

```
listener.protobuf.internal = 127.0.0.1:8087
```

when i change localhost to My IP then riak-shell is not working

**after changing to IP** as

```
listener.protobuf.internal = 172.16.27.252:8087
```

then it's giving error as 
[image]

Comment: i am able get output through java client whatever we save to riak ts, but in shell not able to run any sql query, earlier i was able to run, but after chnaging localhost to IP getting this error. Suggest how we resolve this issues.

Comment: have solve this while making chnages in riak_shell.config file from localhost to my Server IP  as given below

[
 {riak_shell, [
              {logging, off},
              {cookie, riak},
              {show_connection_status, false},
              {nodes, [
                       'riak@172.16.27.252','riak@172.16.28.18','riak@172.16.28.16'
                      ]}
             ]}
].